# Sum, Median and Mean of rainfall over different periods in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, data-analysis

I am in the need of getting the sum, mean and median of rainfall for every month from 01/01/1889 (dd/mm/yyyy) until 18/05/2016. I.e. Every January month from 1889-2016 the sum of rainfall is xxxx, median is xxxx and mean is xxxx. Repeat for the rest of the months. Since it has 1800 years a lot of functions don't work and since its such a large data set 1-46526 cells filter does not work either.

Please find the following examples of how my data is setup.

I have dates in column A setup in yyyymmdd and the same dates converted into dd/mm/yyyy format in column F, rainfall is in column G.

[image: Data example 1]
[image: Data example 2]

Comment: to avoid the issue with year being pre 1900, you could increase (temporarily) the year for every date by 11 or more years.  When you are done, subtract the number of years you added.

Comment: Take a read of this [article on pre 1900 dates](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo as the graph below

In cell E2, write `=SUM(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$8)=$D2,$B$2:$B$8,""))` then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

In cell F2, write `=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$8)=$D2,$B$2:$B$8,""))` then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

In cell G2, write `=MEDIAN(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$8)=$D2,$B$2:$B$8,""))` then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

[image]